# On a continuous function as a substitute of the prime-counting function in the second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture satisfying certain asymptotics

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, examples, continuity

It it well-known that the prime-counting function $\pi(x)$ satisfies the prime number theorem and that were in the literature two related conjectures to this arithmetic function, these are: the Riemann hypothesis, I mean in this ocassion the equivalence due to von Koch ([1]), and the second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture (see the corresponding Wikipedia or [2])

I would like to know if it is in the literature a continuous function $f(t)$ on  some interval $(L,\infty)$, for some constant $L>0$, satisfying the following conditions $$\pi(x+y)\leq \pi(x)+f(y)\tag{C1}$$
for all positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x\leq y$ where $L<x$. And also that satisfies 
$$|f(x)-\pi(x)|=O\left(\sqrt{x}\log x\right)\tag{C2}$$
as $x\to\infty$, and also satisfying the asymptotic equivalence $$\pi(x)\sim f(x)\tag{C3}$$
as $x\to\infty$.

> **Question*.** Do you know any continuous function $f(x)$, on our interval $(L,\infty)$ being $L$ a positive constant, satisfying previous conditions $\text{(C1)}$, $\text{(C2)}$ and $\text{(C3)}$? Alternatively, is it possible to prove the existence of such continuous function? If it is in the literature please refer it answering as a reference request and I try to search and read the statement from the literature. **Many thanks.**

If isn't in the literature I'm asking about what work can be done to 
elucidate the problem in my Question, that is at least feedback about the existence of such function: I don't know if it's easy to prove that such a continuous function (and its corresponding interval $(L,\infty)$) exists. If you can to prove the existence and you want to add more remarks about the function(s) $f(x)$ feel free to do it.

### References:

[1] Helge von Koch , *Sur la distribution des nombres premiers*, Acta Mathematica volume 24, Article number: 159 (1901).

[2] G. H. Hardy and J. E. Littlewood, *Some problems of ‘Partitio numerorum’ III: On the expression of a number as a sum of primes*, Acta Math. (44): 1–70 (1923).

---

*An hour ago I've asked a similar question without a good mathematical content (thanks for the user in comments), I've updated it in a new post.

Comment: @Wojowu many thanks for your feedback in my (previous recent) deleted post (now I understand that from the asymptotic of the logarithmic integral and the function $\frac{x}{\log x}$, and that $\frac{y}{\log y}$ is a continuous and strictly increasing function the question in my deleted post has not a good mathematical content). Feel free to add your valuable comments again.

Comment: Many thanks for the upvoter.

Comment: While I was searching literature I've found the paper by professor Matt Visser, *Primes and the Lambert* $W$ *function*, Cornell University Library (November 2013); the reference that I know is arXiv:1311.2324v2